# Call to a member function setName() on a non-object in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to edit a form i get the form with existing values correctly but when i try to put new data in fields and submit the form i get an error of Call to a member function setName() on a non-object

My controller method is

```
public function editAction(Request $request){
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $group_id = $request->query->get('id');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $patent_group = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:PmPatentgroups')->find($group_id);
    //echo '<pre>';
    //print_r($patent_group);
    //echo '</pre>';
    $form = $this->createForm(new PatentgroupType(), $patent_group);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $name = $form["name"]->getData();
        $description = $form["description"]->getData();
        $patent_group->setName($name);
        $patent_group->setDescription($description);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MunichInnovationGroupBundle_portfolio'));
    }
    return $this->render('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:Patentgroups:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'group_id' => $group_id
    ));
}
```

This is what I get in $patent_group

```
 MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPatentgroups Object
(
[id:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPatentgroups:private] => c3e0eb98-ada5-11e1-96a5-9787dec335c2
[name:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPatentgroups:private] => Zoha Ali khan
[description:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPatentgroups:private] => No Description Provided for this Group
[portfolio_id:MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPatentgroups:private] => Proxies\MunichInnovationGroupBundleEntityPmPortfoliosProxy Object
    (
        [_entityPersister:Proxies\MunichInnovationGroupBundleEntityPmPortfoliosProxy:private] => Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister Object
            (
                [_class:protected] => Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata Object
                    (
                        [reflFields] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => ReflectionProperty Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => id
                                        [class] => MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios
                                    )

                                [portfolioName] => ReflectionProperty Object
                                    (
                                        [name] => portfolioName
                                        [class] => MunichInnovationGroup\Bundle\Entity\PmPortfolios
                                    )
```

What i am doing wrong here as i am getting this error

```
Call to a member function setName() on a non-object
```

Any Ideas?
Thanks in advance

Comment: `var_dump(is_object($patent_group))`

Comment: @Sarfraz can you please explain your comment a bit :)

Comment: By the way it returns boolean true

Comment: I have not worked with symphony but check if `$patent_group` is an object.

Comment: @Sarfraz yes it returns true it means it is an object

Comment: You are not creating an instance of the class anywhere using the `new` keyword to use its methods. Let's suppose you want to use class `foo`, you need to put `setName` method inside it so that it is available to you. You can learn more about it here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html. In other words, with your `$patent_group = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:PmPatentgroups')->find($group_id);` it returns something which does not have the `setName` setter method or the actual class you need.

Comment: i dont need to create a new instance I want to edit the $patent_group object

Comment: try to dump `$form->getData();`, it should be an instance of your PmPatentgroups Object and if not then you have a problem with your bindRequest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Fix: Kindly comment whether it is a good solution or not

```
public function editAction(Request $request){
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $group_id = $request->query->get('id');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $patentgroup = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:PmPatentgroups')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$group_id));
    $form = $this->createForm(new PatentgroupType(), $patentgroup);
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->bindRequest($request);
        $group_id = $form["id"]->getData();
        $name = $form["name"]->getData();
        $description = $form["description"]->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
        $patentgroup = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:PmPatentgroups')->findOneBy(array('id'=>$group_id));
        $patentgroup->setName($name);
        $patentgroup->setDescription($description);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('MunichInnovationGroupBundle_portfolio'));
    }
    return $this->render('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:Patentgroups:edit.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'group_id' => $group_id
    ));
}
```

Comment: This controller do a "LITTLE" more than it have .... It's a good practice to migrate a good part of that code elsewhere (managers,services, and so on)

Answer (score 0):

your object $patent_group most probably hasn't been found in your DB.

Comment: What do you mean by in DB? As a table field? I m just saving what I get from the query in $patent_group

Comment: hmm this line :  $patent_group = $em->getRepository('MunichInnovationGroupBundle:PmPatentgroups')->find($group_id); what did you mean with that ?

Comment: When i visit the edit page for the ist time where the form is rendered it says $patent_group is an object and and when I edit the form and post it and when the if condition is executed it say false

Comment: inside the POST condition the $_patent_group does not remain object anymore strange :(